# Not able to redirect from one page to another page

Tags: spring, web-services, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing web app using spring..

## Exception

The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose  that one exists.

## Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/details/{id}")
public String productDtails(@PathVariable int id)
{   
ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("Detail");
model.addObject("prdt",pd.getById(id));
return "redirect:/detail/{id}";
}
```

## Jsp

```
<c:url var="url" value="/details/${x.id }"></c:url>
<a href="${url}">
<img src="resources/Images/${x.id}.png"/>

${x.product_Name}</a>
```

Comment: You are having any method with request mapping "detail/{id}" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect anywhere to our project we can use `contextPath`

### Solved Code

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addtoCart/${prdt.id}"><input type= "button" Value="Buy Now" class="button"/></a>
```